# Print specific values and keys in a dictionary on separate lines in python3

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a dictionary with several keys and values. I want to be able to print specific keys line by line.

```
my_dictionary = {'vendor': 'Maker', 'hostname': 'PC1',
   'os_version': 'OSv1', 'uptime': 7260, 
'serial_number': '9NJFB4', 'model': 'Iv2', 'fqdn': 'PC1.lab.local'}
```

I want to be able to print for example:

```
fqdn: PC1.lab.local
serial_number: 9NJFB4
model: Iv2
uptime: 7260
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a simple iteration over the dict and print the key, value if the key is present in your needed keys.

```
my_dictionary = {'vendor': 'Maker', 'hostname': 'PC1',
   'os_version': 'OSv1', 'uptime': 7260, 
'serial_number': '9NJFB4', 'model': 'Iv2', 'fqdn': 'PC1.lab.local'}

needed_keys = ['fqdn', 'serial_number', 'model', 'uptime']

for key, val in my_dictionary.items():
    if key in needed_keys:
        print(f'{key} : {val}')

# Output

uptime : 7260
serial_number : 9NJFB4
model : Iv2
fqdn : PC1.lab.local
```

If the python version is older than 3.6 which don't have support for f-strings use the following code with `format` to print the key-value

```
my_dictionary = {'vendor': 'Maker', 'hostname': 'PC1',
   'os_version': 'OSv1', 'uptime': 7260, 
'serial_number': '9NJFB4', 'model': 'Iv2', 'fqdn': 'PC1.lab.local'}

needed_keys = ['fqdn', 'serial_number', 'model', 'uptime']

for key, val in my_dictionary.items():
    if key in needed_keys:
        print('{key} : {val}'.format(key=key, val=val))
```

Comment: For some reason I am getting the following error: SyntaxError: invalid syntax on the print line.

Comment: What is your python version.?

Comment: I am running Python 3.5.2

Comment: Great solution Sreeram! That is exactly what I wanted to do. Thanks!

Comment: @JHCTac Glad to hear it helped.

Answer (score 1):

use python dictionary items function

```
for (key, value) in my_dictionary.items():
    print('{key}: {value}'.format(key=key, value=value))
```

Comment: I am trying this code but I am getting an error. I see that there is a } bracket there at the end of the print line but there is no opening {

Answer (score 0):

May be pprint is what you are looking for

```
import pprint
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(width=41, compact=True)
filtered_keys = ['fqdn','serial_number','uptime']
pp.pprint({k:v for k,v in my_dictionary.items() if k in filtered_keys})

#
{'fqdn': 'PC1.lab.local', 
 'serial_number': '9NJFB4', 
 'uptime': 7260}
```

Comment: I don't want to print the entire dictionary only certain keys.

Comment: Almost there I am not sure if I am doing something wrong.  I added the code but its printing it out all on one line.  However it is getting me the keys and values I want.

Comment: pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(width=41, compact=True), play with width values, if you are not getting it right